# NestJS architecture and testing

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, nestjs

I am currently working on a project using NestJS and when it comes to testing I think the architecture is bit of a pain. As far as I understand the recommended approach is to have two layers: controllers and service.

### Controllers

The controllers is fairly easy to test when needed, although I do not understand the need for testingModules (same goes for services):

```js
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  controllers: [MyController]
  providers: [MyService] // jest.mock is used to mock MyService
}).compile();

controller = module.get(MyController)
```

It seems fairly easy to inject whatever mock I need directly:

```js
controller = new MyController(new MyService()) // again jest.mock is used to mock MyService
```

For me the latter example is shorter, easier to understand and expresses exactly what I want to test. It does not test that my dependency injection works, but (at least in our application) that is checked by NestJS at startup.

### Services

When it comes to testing services, I find myself doing a **lot** of mocking of repositories.

```js
const spy = jest.spyOn(repository, 'save')
  .mockReturnValueOnce(null) // something like jest-when should be introduced

await service.create('Question on Stackoverflow', 'I do not get it...')

expect(spy.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual({
  title: 'Question on Stackoverflow',
  content: 'I do not get it...',
  comments: [] // no initial comments
})
```

Every tutorial/example I've found suggests putting the Repository in the service. I've thought about putting it in the controller (or resolver for GraphQL), but is just doesn't feel like the right separation of responsibilities and leads to duplication of code when both Rest and GraphQL is used. For me the best approach seems to be creating another layer (or add functions to my entity classes), which would then be responsible for the domain/business logic. This is easy to test (no mocks and no promises)

```js
const question = Domain.create('Question on Stackoverflow', 'I do not get it...')
// or const question = Question.create('Question on Stackoverflow', 'I do not get it...')

expect(question).toEqual({
  title: 'Question on Stackoverflow',
  content: 'I do not get it...',
  comments: [] // no initial comments
})
```

The service would then only be responsible for I/O which seems like a great separation of concerns.

My question is now: does this make sense when it comes to NestJS? It seems like this is not the suggested way to do it. Maybe I am missing some important stuff or maybe I am complicating the architecture more that necessary.

Thanks for your inputs in advance
Andreas

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow ! For your controller part, how would you instanciate a controller that has 15 service, and each service has 15 service, recursively ? That can get confusing really fast.

Comment: I still need to provide the service in the module and if they are all mocks the next layer of service would not be necessary. For E2E tests it is another story.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to do something like

```js
const myController = new MyConstroller(new MyService());
```

is great in theory, but once your service starts having dependencies on other services (Redis, TypeORM, other services in your application) it can quickly become handful to work with

```js
const myController = new MyController(
  new MyService(
    new RedisService(redisOptions),
    new MyEntityReposiotry(myEntityRepoOptions),
    new OtherService(new RedisService(redisOpitons))
  )
);
```

and sure you can set these to variables before making your controller so you're instantiating less classes, but you're still having to make a lot of these injections yourself.

With the Nest architecture and Test class you can do something quick like

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
    controllers: [MyController],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: MyService,
        useValue: myServiceMock
      }
    ],
  }).compile();
});
```

And now you easily have a reference to what your mock for my service is, you can define the general structure and default return values of the service functions, and can still get the reference to the service and controller class with `module.get<MySerivce|MyController>(MyService|MyController)`.

Of course, you can always use `jest.mock()` to start a basic stub and mock the return values as you see fit, but keep in mind how that can affect the look of your tests. One of the draws of NestJS is that it *is* opinionated and it has a certain way it likes to look.

If you'd like to see examples, [you an check out this repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) with a bunch of test samples for different types of projects, including rxjs, typeorm, and graphql.

Comment: Maybe a real-world example is needed, but in the [cat.service.spec](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/blob/master/apps/typeorm-graphql-sample/src/cat/cat.service.spec.ts), I do not see the point of the TestModule. Why not just create the service with the value provided in the Repo provider? I would still use mocks (just passing it directly to the service ctor instead of using the provider in the module) which will avoid the second example.

Comment: Again, it would be fine if the service only has one or two basic dependencies, but when it has multiple dependencies, or when it's dependencies have dependencies, it gets a little hard to "just pass it directly". [Here is a service from my main repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/blob/master/apps/api/src/app/auth/auth/auth.service.ts), and [here is its test](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/blob/master/apps/api/src/app/auth/auth/auth.service.spec.ts). I don't worry about mocking the entirety of the classes, just what's necessary to make the class run.

Comment: I still do not see it. I have forked your repo and in [this commit](https://github.com/afkpost/zeldaPlay/commit/cf123c29b217ffa148d610ef7027407b81286d67?diff=split) I have removed the testing module: it's fever lines of code, there is no IOC container (no providing of a mapping from the injection name to the instance) and the dependencies are stronger typed (a helper for modules is fairly trivial, but it has to support all the ways of adding providers). For me both ways handles the dependencies the same way (using mocks) - I just don't see the use for testing modules for unit tests.

Comment: And that's fine, you don't have to use the utilities provided if you don't want to. I just figured I would give my example as to why it can be helpful. It keeps all of your tests looking similar and most other devs who use Nest would know how to read them pretty quickly, but that doesn't mean this is the only way to do it at all, and you're free to do it how you want.